# Distribution of function of random variable $y = (x_{0}-x)^n$ where $x$ is $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Need to compute distribution of function of random variable $y = (x_{0}-x)^n$ where $x$ and $x_0$ are both less than -3, $x<x_0$ and $x$ is distributed as $N(0,1)$

I have pages of ink on paper attempts but am overwhelmed (and frankly, a bit out of practice) ...

My first round through gives me that the probability density function for $y$ is

$$f(y)=\frac{1}{n\sqrt{2\pi}}y^{\frac{1}{n}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x_0^2+y^2+2x_0y\right)^\frac{1}{n}}$$

How would I apply the fact that we're out in the left tail

Comment: Is $x$ a random variable or a constant? How about $A$?

Comment: thanks for clarfication question ... yes, $x$ is a normally distribution random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ .... $A$, $n$ and $x_0$ are constants

Comment: It sounds like $x$ and $x_0$ are going to have a [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution), given that you said they're both less than $-3$. This is not going to be pretty, to say the least.

Comment: yeah ... it was getting messy ... $x<x_0<-3$

Comment: I have preliminary simulation data which suggests that the distribution of $y$ is Weibull with a Weibull exponent of ~$1/2n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very sure if I am doing right, but let me give a try by using the defintions: first I would like to write $X$ and $Y$ for the $x$ given in the OP, since for me it is more comfortable to use $X$ and $Y$ for a random variables... Now you want to derive the distribution of $Y$. Then it suffices to derive the distribution function of $Y$, namely, you want to derive the explicit form of $P(Y\leq t)$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Due to the defintion given by the OP, that is to calculate $P((x_0-X)^n\leq t)$. Due to the definition, we should notice that $P(X\geq x_0)=0$, therefore $P((x_0-X)^n\leq t)=P((x_0-X)^n\leq t,X<x_0)$. For $t<0$, this is obviously an empty set; for $t>0$, we have $P(Y\leq t)=P(x_0-t^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq X<x_0)=\int_{x_0-t^{\frac{1}{n}}}^{x_0}f(\sigma)d\sigma=\Phi(x_0)-\Phi(x_0-t^{\frac{1}{n}})$, where $f$ is the density of $X$ and $\Phi$ is the distribution function of $X$. Now calculating the derivative of the distribution function you can obtain the density, and in our case, we can apply the chain rule: $\frac{d}{dt}P(Y\leq t)=f(x_0-t^{\frac{1}{n}})t^{\frac{1-n}{n}}$. It seems that this is in fact a very easy derivation, so I am not sure if I am mistaken or misunderstood the meaning of the problem. Please tell me if I made a mistake.

Comment: Thank you for this!  Just so I understand, at any point, did you utilize that we are looking at the tail of the Normal distribution? Or do these results hold for the entire range of the original density function?

Comment: Also, do you need to normalize the resultant transformed density function?

Comment: Well usally if we say $X$ is normal distributed, then we think it takes value on the whole $\mathbb{R}$. So for me it is a little confusing, since you said your $X$ is normally distributed and it is bounded. So my advice is that you can give a precise definiton of your $X$, for instance give the precise density function $f(t)$ of $X$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then it is really easy to solve the problem from this start point.

Comment: It's bounded in the $+x$ direction (by $x_0$), not bounded in the $-x$ direction.

Comment: $\Phi(x)=N(0,1)$ for $x<x_0$ and $\Phi(x)=0$ for $x>x_0$

Comment: What is the meaning of $\phi(x)=N(0,1)$? You need to clarify this, since $\phi$ is a distribution function, it is from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and $N(0,1)$ is a distribution but not a real number.

Comment: $N(0,1)$ is the normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.  I typically do not use capital letters with hollow interiors ...

Comment: I think the problem here is the notations. We usually use $\phi$ to denote the distribution function, namely, $\phi(x)=P(X\leq x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Also in your case, it is a little confusing if you directly say $X$ is normally distriduted for $X<x_0$, since I have never seen this in the literatures that I have ever read. An alternative to say this is that the density function of $X$ will coincide (up to a prefactor due to normalization reason) with the normal density function for $x<x_0$, namely $f_{X}(x)=\lambda f_{N(0,1)}(x)$ for $x<x_0$.

Comment: Normalizing (by simply dividing by $\Phi(x_0)$), I obtain $P(Y\leqslant t) = 1-e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^{2/n}}e^{x_0t^{1/n}}$